# Unable to call a injector service in the promise of the Javascript function which is loaded dynamically and assigned to global variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, paypal, angular8

## Issue

I am trying to integrate paypal with Angular. When I call an injected service inside a function of the promise returned I am unable to do it. I need help in achieving it.

Here are the steps I am trying to do.

1. Click on the load PayPal button.
2. Load the dynamically injected Braintree and PayPal sdk.
3. Authorize into PayPal and get the nonce token.
4. Pass the nonce token generated into the service which is injected into the component.

### Code below

#### app.component.html

```
<button (click)="initializePayPal()">load paypal</button>
<div id="pay-pal-btn"></div>
```

#### app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private backEndService: BackEndService) {}
  initializePayPal() {
    get("https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/3.71.1/js/client.min.js", () => {
      get(
        "https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/3.71.1/js/paypal-checkout.min.js",
        () => {
          console.log("loaded");
          this.loadPayPalSDK();
        }
      );
    });
  }

  private loadPayPalSDK(): void {
    braintree.client
      .create({
        authorization: "sandbox_5rnr7xqg_kx8tzdyvfcrnxq5y"
      })
      .then(clientInstance => {
        // Create a PayPal Checkout component.
        return braintree.paypalCheckout.create({
          client: clientInstance
        });
      })
      .then(paypalCheckoutInstance => {
        return paypalCheckoutInstance.loadPayPalSDK({
          vault: true
        });
      })
      .then(paypalCheckoutInstance => {
        return paypal
          .Buttons({
            locale: "en_US",
            fundingSource: paypal.FUNDING.PAYPAL,
            style: {
              height: 40
            },
            createBillingAgreement() {
              return paypalCheckoutInstance.createPayment({
                flow: "vault"
              });
            },
            onApprove(data, actions) {
              return paypalCheckoutInstance
                .tokenizePayment(data)
                .then(payload => {
                  console.log(payload.nonce);
                  this.backEndService.addToken(payload);
                });
            },

            onCancel(data) {},

            onError(err) {
              //
            }
          })
          .render("#pay-pal-btn");
      });
  }
}
```

#### Back End Service backend.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class BackEndService {
  addToken(token: string) {
    // here is am going to use the token generated and pass this value to backend service using http request.
    console.log("token" + token);
  }
}
```

### Expected Resolution

I need to call the injected service upon the tokenizePayment method is called.

Thanks a lot in advance

## StackBlitz URL

#### https://stackblitz.com/edit/kp-angular-paypal?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Why not use this library made for angular? https://github.com/Enngage/ngx-paypal

Comment: Thanks bjdose for taking time and responding. I am already aware of this library. But why do I even need to use this library when I can implement my own in simple steps, I just need to know to way to call my required method from the service injector.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having right now is related to the scope.

```
// you are losing the scope on calling paypal.Buttons
// because this function has its own scope and it is not possible to
// get the backend service which has another scope (this)
return paypal.Buttons({
           onApprove() {
              return paypalCheckoutInstance
                .tokenizePayment(data)
                .then(payload => {
                  this.backendservice // <- this is undefined because of scope
                });
             }
           })
```

However, I found two ways to handle this case.

1. Use a static method.

```
        
return paypal.Buttons({
            onApprove() {
              return paypalCheckoutInstance
                .tokenizePayment(data)
                .then(payload => {
                  BackEndService.sendToken(payload.nonce);
                });
             }
           })
```

`backend.service.ts`

```
export class BackEndService {
  // our static method
  static sendToken(token: string) {
        console.log("[backend service] send token", token);
  }
```

2. Pass our scope indirectly using an object with our service reference.

```
  // create an object with my scope calling our service
  // we need to pass this object to our 
  // method loadPayPalSDK
  config = {
    onApprove: (token: string) => {
      this.backEndService.addToken(token);
    }
  };


// I need my config here
private loadPayPalSDK(config = this.config): void {
 // code omitted ...
 return paypal.Buttons({
            onApprove() {
              return paypalCheckoutInstance
                .tokenizePayment(data)
                .then(payload => {
                  config.onApprove(payload.nonce);
                });
             }
           })

}
```

Comment: I don't think both the answers work in this case. For the first response, you are injecting static for method level but not class level. But still the class should be accessed through 'this'.  And comes to your second option config should be static here inorder to access it.

Comment: You can check it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/kp-angular-paypal-9rsd4f?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: static config = {
    onApprove: (token: string) => {
      this.backEndService(token)
    }
  };

Comment: It is not necessary to use static on config because I'm passing it as an argument, check my link above, two ways are working fine